# Need some help understanding Peltier Plates

Tags: temperature, thermoelectricity

When shopping for peltier plates for a school project, I saw a seller that says that the plates are rated to 40 watts. I'm assuming this is talking about when they are used for cooling though, and not as a thermoelectric generator. If heated to the temperature limit, would the plates be able to create 40 watts of electricity as a generator as well?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. It depends very much on your specific device and how it was designed and built.

Efficiency of Peltier plates when used as thermoelectric generators is something like 2%. I've seen some in trailer parts stores which use a temperature differential of hundreds of degrees and they put out about 10 watts.

To aid you in your quest, research the Seebeck (spelling?) Effect.